# MVC Refresh view with multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Here is my issue. I had an index page that loaded a partial view containing a list of employees and their utilization. In that page there is a dropdown that allowed the user to filter to only see people who's supervisor is selected from the dropdown. This all functioned fine until I tried a second dropdown with the starting week for the report. Now whenever I select either dropdown the partial view does not load at all. I debugged thru the controller and all the steps where the data loads and everything looks correct, it just displays an empty table.

#### View Code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Resource Utilization";
}

<h3>Resource Utilization Totals</h3>

<Section class="form-group">
    <div float:left> @Html.DropDownList("ProjectLeadId", null, "All Resources", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:250px;" })</div>
    <div float:right> @Html.DropDownList("ProjectWeeks", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:250px;" })</div>
</Section>


<div id="report">
    @Html.Action("GetList")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ProjectLeadId, #ProjectWeeks").change(function () {
                $("#report").load("/ResourceUtilizationReport/GetList?LeadId=" + $("#ProjectLeadId").val() + "&StartWeek=" + $("#ProjectWeeks").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

#### Controller Code

```
 public PartialViewResult GetList(int? LeadId, DateTime? StartWeek)
 {
     var viewModel = new UtilizationViewModel();
     viewModel.Utilization = _utilizationReportImporter.GetUtilization(12, LeadId, StartWeek);
     return PartialView(viewModel);          
 }
```

Comment: When you debug through GetList viewModel.Utilization is returning values?

Comment: Yes and it is returning the values I would expect it to return. Also if I pass the WeekEnding as a null everything renders properly.

Comment: The first time the `GetList` action gets called, does it *paint* anything?

Comment: The first time it is called it creates the full table that it is supposed to be displaying.

Comment: Additional info. Anytime I set the "ProjectWeeks" dropdown to it's default value, which is null, everything displays properly. Also if I type in the URL for the partial view and pass both of the parameters in the URL it displays the data for me.

Comment: Can you provide the element(s) being generated for ProjectWeeks? My guess is that the values are being rendered as /Date[ticks]/ which may be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in your `js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var data = {
                      "LeadId": $("#ProjectLeadId").val(),
                      "StartWeek": $("#ProjectWeeks").val()
                   }
        $("#ProjectLeadId, #ProjectWeeks").change(function () {
            $("#report").load("/ResourceUtilizationReport/GetList", data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Make sure the `x.val()` calls are returning what is expected. Using the second parameter to the `load` method makes sure `JQuery` creates the right url.

Comment: When I tried this neither dropdown did anything on change.

Comment: When I use XHR in chrome to view the data it shows the data correctly in the preview window.

Comment: After the `load` method finishes and you see the preview, have you inspected the HTML?

Comment: Yes, the HTML on the page never changes even though I have stepped thru the view and verified it received and processed the new model. When I hit F12 in Chrome and look at Network, XHR preview it shows everything as it should be displaying.

Comment: Have you seen any error on the Chrome console? Maybe there is something failing in `JQuery` or something

Comment: There are no errors. And both Chrome and IE developer tools show that the response body contains a properly formatted table to display. The table is just never being posted to the view.

Comment: There is a `JQuery.load(url, [data], [complete])` and you could use the `complete` parameter, which is `Function( String responseText, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )` to see the response you are getting and investigate further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113535/discussion-between-luiso-and-mikeym).